# Compilation error in a view(.cshtml) file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I think you know about online MvcMusicStore application tutorial at mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com. I am developing this project under MS SQl Server 2008 professional edition instead of Compact edition using MVC3. And i used **Link to Sql** class as model class. It was working as usual. But, the code inside the view file Browse.cshtml

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}
<h2>Genre : @Model.Name</h2>
<ul>
@foreach(var album in @Model.Albums)
{ 
<li>@album.Title</li>
}
</ul>
```

generates a compilation error message as,

Browse.cshtml(7,2): error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type  'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>' because 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

So, can you give me a solution to get rid of it. Thank you.
In addition, **Genre class**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Genres")]
public partial class Genre : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _GenreId;

    private string _Name;

    private string _Description;

    private EntitySet<Album> _Albums;
    ...
```

**Album class,**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Albums")]
public partial class Album : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _AlbumId;

    private int _GenreId;

    private int _ArtistId;

    private string _Title;

    private decimal _Price;

    private string _AlbumArtUrl;

    private EntitySet<Cart> _Carts;

    private EntitySet<OrderDetail> _OrderDetails;

    private EntityRef<Artist> _Artist;

    private EntityRef<Genre> _Genre;
...
```

Comment: Can you post your Genre class?

Comment: Classes are built automatically by visual studio 2010 using link to sql class having large declaration.Yet, I included Genre and Album Classes. check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, i got the solution. There was missing of an assembly reference. I just added an assembly reference in the web.config file. i.e.,

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

That's it.